# How to insert VARIANT or ARRAY data types into Snowflake with pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains several columns that are lists. I'd like to insert them into my Snowflake table as `ARRAY` data types.

Traditionally, I've worked with PostgreSQL, and simply inserted as `df_to_insert.to_sql(TABLE_NAME, sqlalchemy_connection, **other_parameters)`.

However, I'm struggling to insert into Snowflake. When I have a column that is a list, the sqlAlchemy Snowflake dialect believes it is a string:

> Expression type does not match column data type, expecting ARRAY but
>   got VARCHAR(2) for column NAME_OF_COLUMN_WITH_LISTS

I've tried given the sqlAlchemy engine a hint that the column is not a string by adding in explicit dtypes:

```
df_to_insert.to_sql("MY_SNOWFLAKE_TABLE_NAME",
                     snowflake_connection,
                     if_exists="append",
                     index=False,
                     dtype={'NAME_OF_COLUMN_WITH_LISTS': sqlalchemy.types.JSON})
```

This only gets me:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.AttributeError)
>   'SnowflakeDialect' object has no attribute '_json_serializer'

What's the best way to insert data into Snowflake tables of variant / array types and still use pandas / sqlalchemy? Or is there no good way to do this yet?

Comment: Have you tried `sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY` ?

Comment: @ResidentSleeper
sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY is not working if you have a variable length list elements in a pd dataframe column. assume first element of this column is ['a', 'b', 'c'] and len = 3, and second element is ['a'] whose len =1, then it will cause Inconsistent number of values in the VALUES clause expecting 3 but got 1

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward way to work around this would be to:

1. Write the dataframe to a local text file.
2. Use PUT command to upload to a Snowflake STAGE
3. run `create or replace table as select from stage` and cast the fields into their proper types in the select statement.

Comment: this [blog post](https://calogica.com/sql/snowflake/python/2019/06/12/snowflake-pandas.html) has an example to the above stages